# How to add validation for Dropdownchoice and Checkbox in Wicket java

Tags: java, html, checkbox, wicket, dropdownchoice

I have a checkbox and dropdown in a html page . On click of submit if both of them are selected , their should be a error message that any one of them should be mandatory field  and asked to select one value atleast.

I created a new class as as FormValidator implementing IValidator and override the validate method. But i am unaware how to use the dropdown choice value and checkbox value on submit method call ad how to display in html .

Java code -

```
IModel<Project> dropdownModel =   new PropertyModel<Project>(criteria,"selectedBillableProject");
        DropDownChoice<Project> billableProjectsList = new DropDownChoice<>(
                "projectsList",
                dropdownModel,
                billableProjects,
                new ChoiceRenderer<Project>("fullNameWithCustomer"));
        billableProjectsList.setLabel(new ResourceModel("printMonth.billable"));
        
        form.add(billableProjectsList);
```

}

```
protected void onSubmit() {
           .....
            validateInputComponents(reportCriteria);
.....
}

public void validateInputComponents(ReportCriteria reportCriteria){

          add(new FormComponentValidator(reportCriteria.getSelectedBillableProject(), unbillableProjectsView.getModelObject()));      

        }
```

I have updated the FormComponentValidtor similar to the :https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Validating+related+fields

But its resulting in below error onSubmit (). 11-26@22:37:25 ERROR org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle - Error during processing error message
java.lang.IllegalStateException: STREAM
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.getWriter(Response.java:693)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:152)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:152)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.getWriter(SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.java:125)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.servlet.ServletWebResponse.write(ServletWebResponse.java:109)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.HeaderBufferingWebResponse.write(HeaderBufferingWebResponse.java:179)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.BufferedWebResponse$WriteCharSequenceAction.invoke(BufferedWebResponse.java:171)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.BufferedWebResponse.writeTo(BufferedWebResponse.java:602)
at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:232)
at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:175)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:890)
at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.executeExceptionRequestHandler(RequestCycle.java:310)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.executeExceptionRequestHandler(RequestCycle.java:319)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.executeExceptionRequestHandler(RequestCycle.java:319)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.executeExceptionRequestHandler(RequestCycle.java:319)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.executeExceptionRequestHandler(RequestCycle.java:319)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.executeExceptionRequestHandler(RequestCycle.java:319)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.executeExceptionRequestHandler(RequestCycle.java:319)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.executeExceptionRequestHandler(RequestCycle.java:319)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.executeExceptionRequestHandler(RequestCycle.java:319)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.executeExceptionRequestHandler(RequestCycle.java:319)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.executeExceptionRequestHandler(RequestCycle.java:319)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:233)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:289)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:259)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:201)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:282)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1484)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1484)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:151)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1476)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Am i missing something . Please help

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: @OrAssayag - updated the code

Comment: The issue is fixed and i am able to display the error message as per the request . But one thing is once i select the valid inputs and submit , the feedback panel errror message still shows up . Any suggestion on how to clear the messages

Comment: @OrAssayag - the feedback message displayed is retained in the page even after valid inout form submission . I tried SelectionForm.getFeedbackMessages() , component.getFeedbackMessages() , everything is empty . Unable to clear them . Please let me know any inputs .. trying from longtime

Answer (score 2):

looks like your are missing a FeedbackPanel in your form to display validation errors/messages. Take a look at the user guide here and follow the entire example:

https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/8.x/single.html#_form_validation_and_feedback_messages

Comment: i added the feedback <div style="color: red" wicket:id="feedback"></div> in the html page . it displays the error . But i want it to display custom error message and has to display only if both checkbox and dropdown are empty .

Comment: Look at the live example here for a complete use case of a custom validator and message:
https://wicket-guide.herokuapp.com/customvalidator/?0
Then you can use a IFormValidator to handle multiple input fields.

Comment: can i add the custom validation using IFormValidator on the method - OnSubmit()

Comment: Please help with some inputs on how to add validation for multiple components (Dropdown & Checkbox)  onsubmit()

Comment: i am able to retreive the dropdown and checkbox values onSubmit() method , but not sure how to use the validator to add the custom error message . Could you please help

Comment: Maybe this old example from wiki page is what you need:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Validating+related+fields

Comment: - I followed the link and tried to use IFormValidator . Please let me know how to convert the CheckBox to FormComponent values , since its requierd for validation

Comment: the feedback message displayed is retained in the page even after valid inout form submission . I tried SelectionForm.getFeedbackMessages() , component.getFeedbackMessages() , everything is empty . Unable to clear them . Please let me know any inputs .. trying from longtime